# Number of possible passwords with same characters

Tags: combinatorics

We have a password with length of 6 characters, out of a possible 27 letters, 10 digits and 8 special characters.

My questions are:

- A: How many possible combinations there are?
- B: How many combinations have at least two same characters?
- C: How many combinations have at least one special character?
- D: How many combinations have exactly two same characters (and others are different characters)?

The answer to A is $(27+10+8)^6$ but B, C and D are a mystery to me. Could I have some advice on the problem?

Comment: 27 letters? maybe you should ask on Spanish language stack exchange  :-)

Comment: @Joffan, what did you mean?

Comment: @lee it was a joke poking fun at the fact that most commonly for questions of this nature written and asked in English we take the number of characters in the alphabet to be $26$, not $27$.  Of course, this doesn't change the actual math or thought processes, just adjusts the numbers that appear in the final answer.  It does however imply that the OP may not speak English as a first language and might be better served getting an answer in whatever their primary language is.

Comment: @lee Spanish has the usual 26 plus ñ

Comment: @Joffan of course in Spanish "ll" is also considered a separate letter.

Comment: Oh guys stop it! I get it.

Comment: @JMoravitz Very smart notice, I'm from Finland. Can you explain what is that "falling factorial"?

Comment: The falling factorial $n\frac{k}{~}=\underbrace{n\times (n-1)\times\cdots\times (n-k+1)}_{k~\text{terms in the product}}$ counts the number of ordered sequences of length $k$ of characters taken from an $n$-element set such that there is no repetition.  Equivalently, it counts the number of injective functions from a $k$-element set to an $n$-element set.  The set of all such injective functions from $X$ to $Y$ being given the notation $Y\frac{X}{~}$, just as the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ being given the notation $Y^X$.  The proof of the formula follows straight from rule of product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- B:  Consider the opposite event, that no characters are repeated.  Choose the first character.  Once having chosen the first character, choose the second character noting that it can not be the same as the first.  Then choose the third character noting it cannot be either of the first two characters, etc...  Apply rule of product and conclude.

> $45\times 44\times 43\times 42\times 41\times 40$, the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) written commonly as $~_{45}P_6$, as $P(45,6)$, or my preference being $45\frac{6}{~}$

Using this count, subtracting it away from the result from A gives the count we are interested in

> $45^6-45\frac{6}{~}$

- C: Again, consider the opposite event, the number of sequences with no special characters.  The same logic used in A can be used here to count the opposite event.  The same logic used in B taking the opposite event away from the overall total will work here as well.

> $45^6 - 37^6$

- D: Pick the character which is to be repeated.  Pick the locations of that character.  Then, from left to right, pick what characters occupy the remaining positions noting that we may not repeat for these.

> $\binom{6}{2}45\frac{5}{~}$

Comment: Alright I think I might just understand how this works. Thanks a lot for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about $A$: the total number is $45^6$. For $B$ you could count the ones that have all characters different, so $45 \times 44 \ldots \times 40$ and subtract that from the total. For C you can count those without a special character and subtract that amount from the total (so $45^6- 37^6$).

$D$ is the trickiest one: there you can first choose the duplicated character in $45$ ways (all are possible), and then the two positions among the $6$ where they will occur (in $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ ways) and then the $4$ remaining positions go like the different characters under B, with starting with $44$ options, so we get $45 \times 15 \times (44 \times 43 \times 42 \times 41)$ ways.

Comment: In B solution, how do you know that we need to multiply until 40? From where does that 40 come from?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer 5 (6-1) less than 45. We have 6 terms. We substract 1 five times.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer it comes from us knowing we need $6$ (*the length of the password*) terms in the product.  $45$ being the first term in the product, $44$ the second term in the product, if we continue with the terms in the product decreasing by one each time the sixth term in the product will be $40$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma fyi "subtract" not "substract" - I have proof-read far too many documents....